# Angular Call inside cordova success Callback doesn't work

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, callback

I'm running an Ionic App with Angular. I'm using the Diagnostic plug-in of Ionic, but one of the method I use doesn't work with the Diagnostic plugin, so I'm using cordova.plugins.diagnostic.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/diagnostic

https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin

My code is like this :

```
  onClickEnable() {

    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.requestRemoteNotificationsAuthorization({
      successCallback() {
        console.log('Successfully requested remote notifications authorization');
        // HERE I WOULD LIKE TO DO  A   THIS.ROUTER.NAVIGATE(['/page']);
      },
      errorCallback(err) {
        console.error('Error requesting remote notifications authorization: ' + err);
      },
      types: [
       // some value
      ],
      omitRegistration: false,
    });
  }
```

When I run the app, my pop-up shows, and I get the console.log
But what I want is that after the user checked an option on the pop-up, it navigates to another page.
So I'm trying to put a `this.router.navigate(['/page]);`  inside the success Callback, but it doesn't work.

**EDIT : Like this, doesn't work**

```
onClickEnable() {
  cordova.plugins.diagnostic.requestRemoteNotificationsAuthorization({
    successCallback: () => {
      console.log('Successfully requested remote notifications authorization');
      this.router.navigate(['/page']);
    },
    errorCallback: (err) => {
      console.error('Error requesting remote notifications authorization: ' + err);
    
}
```

I know I'm using it the wrong way. Can someone explain me how to do this? I also tried to put a `.then()...` after the method, but it doesn't work.

And if I call the `router.navigate` after the end of the `requestRemoteNotificationsAuthorization` method, it navigates to the page, even if the user did not touch the pop-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I think that inside the cordova successcallback, I was in a different context than my Angular component, that's why my IDE wasn't giving me answers to my completion

[image]

After setting  `const that = this` , and using `that.router.navigate`, it was recognized :
[image]

So my code looks like this now and it solved my problem :

```
onClickEnable() {
  const that = this;
  cordova.plugins.diagnostic.requestRemoteNotificationsAuthorization({
    successCallback: () => {
      console.log('Successfully requested remote notifications authorization');
      that.router.navigate(['/page']);
    },
    errorCallback: (err) => {
      console.error('Error requesting remote notifications authorization: ' + err);
    },
    types: [
      // some value
    ],
    omitRegistration: false,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the documentation for [`requestRemoteNotificationsAuthorization(params)`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova.plugins.diagnostic#requestremotenotificationsauthorization) function, it appears you could send callbacks as inline arrow functions to refer to the `this` keyword in the scope of the enclosing class.

Try the following

```js
onClickEnable() {
  cordova.plugins.diagnostic.requestRemoteNotificationsAuthorization({
    successCallback: () => {
      console.log('Successfully requested remote notifications authorization');
      this.router.navigate(['/page']);
    },
    errorCallback: (err) => {
      console.error('Error requesting remote notifications authorization: ' + err);
    },
    types: [
      // some value
    ],
    omitRegistration: false,
  });
}
```

To learn more about `this` keyword in Javascript and how to access it inside callback functions, you could refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/6513921).

Comment: Yes, that's what I also tried, and it doesn't work. I get the console.log message, but there is no redirection. I can't understand why

Comment: Ok, after defining a ```const that = this ```, and using ```that.router.navigate...```, it worked !

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary. How or where is the `onClickEnable()` bound?

Comment: This method is inside my Component, ```export class ComponentName{...``` , I've got my constructors then  ```constructor(private diagnostic: Diagnostic``` and my method ```onClickEnable```

Comment: I still don't completely understand why doing my method solved my problem...

Comment: I don't mean in that way. Where is the `onClickEnable()` used?

Comment: Sorry, my english is not well. I'm just using a simple button in my HTML template, and this button has a ```click()``` method, like this ```(click)="onClickEnable()"```

Comment: No issues :). Clearly the scope of `this` available in the function is lost inside the callback functions. I'm not sure exactly.

Comment: Yes, I think it's all about contexts. There was a topic about this but I didn't see it, here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback
Defining a new variable makes the content "reachable"

Comment: Thank you very much for your help